# Serialize a tuple of numpy arrays

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, scipy

I have a couple of numpy matrices (3-dimensional to be exact) which are stored in tuples

```
(a1,b1,c1)
(a2,b2,c2)
...
(an,bn,cn)
```

I would like to serialize each tuple into a file that can be read back into Python on another machine (Linux => Windows, both are x86-64). What would be a pythonic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[numpy.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) or numpy.savez_compressed is the way to go.  I've heard, but never experienced issues with certain types of arrays not pickling well.

I'm recalling [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250367/how-to-pickle-numpys-inf-objects) post (doesn't seem to have been much of an issue) as well as something about numpy.void [not pickling](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-February/049015.html).  Likely not an issue, but there it is.

Comment: I want to also add that np.savez seems to do similarly well to scipy.io.savemat. The good thing about savemat is it suppose to operate well with MATLAB .mat files.

Answer (score 1):

Pickle will probably work well

I also saw this: http://thsant.blogspot.com/2007/11/saving-numpy-arrays-which-is-fastest.html

Comment: That link says that Scipy.io gives the best performance both space and time, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah - pickle will probably be less of a hassle if those aren't a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html), [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), [`cPickle`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html), or [`shove`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove). Each of these will let you store most kinds of python objects in a file; `shove` and `shelve` focus on dictionary-like objects that map keys to values, and `shove` will let you use a variety of database-like backends. If you find yourself exceeding the performance limitations on these libraries, consider going the database route, e.g. through [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

I've used each of these libraries, and they work reasonably well within their own niche. I'd start with `pickle` or `shelve`, which are standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use `cPickle`, although I haven't done a formal comparison with other methods. Additionally, I always write the file as binary and use highest protocol setting:

```
f = open('fname.pkl','wb')
cPickle.dump(array_tuple,f,-1)
f.close()
```